# Software for managing comparison of softwares

Tags: web-apps, knowledge-base, knowledge-organization

I want to manage a list of all available time series databases such as [erol's blog](http://www.erol.si/2015/01/the-complete-list-of-all-timeseries-databases-for-your-iot-project/) does, but with more structured content.

My requirements are

- defined format to collect properties of each database. Example properties: "deletion capability", "types of supported interfaces", "required software stack", "license model"
- users can contribute content
- preferably backed by a github repository and github website
- possibility to filter the results and to query for specific content

Existing solutions showing realizations with other content:

- [passify.it](http://www.paasify.it/vendors) ([source](https://github.com/stefan-kolb/paas-profiles)) shows how this can be done with PaaS offerings. However, I find the software too complex to port for other use cases.
- [WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/). Great concept, but not open source (AFAIK)

Comment: I've been looking for something like this myself for a long time. Basically a mixture between http://libraries.io and those curated lists of "awesome" libraries that crop up on Github all the time (e.g. https://github.com/pditommaso/awesome-pipeline). The former has all the real-time data and nice interface, the latter has all the user contributions and curating. But there doesn't seem to be anything that has both.

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile, we created the [ultimate-comparison-framework](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ultimate-comparison).

The core idea is to use markdown for data input, use a GitHub repository for hosting and a browser for rendering. No additional server needed.

Available comparisons are listed at https://ultimate-comparisons.github.io/.

Example: [Ultimate graphframework comparison](https://ultimate-comparisons.github.io/ultimate-graphframework-comparison/).

Comment: That's really cool! Thanks for following up on this!